# How do people test mobile data for mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, testing, mobile

I was wondering how people typically test mobile data for mobile apps. We currently only test on WiFi and that has caused problems in production. Are there services that allow us to use all of our test devices on a mobile data network? Or can we really only buy a sim card for every test device? I just think that's rather clunky, especially since we only need data and not texting or calling. Or should WiFi be sufficient?

Any ideas or thoughts are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi.. When you refer to "all of our test devices", do you intend to mean that you have got real devices with you and you would like to test the app's data across these devices in different network environments such as 2G, 3G etc. without an actual need for a sim card? or u are using the term "all of our test devices" to indicate your target devices for which emulators are being used to in the testing environment?

Answer (score 0):

Typically people test apps based on data speeds used by their targeted audience but we should always use best cases on wifi/broadband and worst cases on 2G/3G mobile networks. there ary many tools and services/platorms free and paid  that you can use online for testing apps on diffrent speeds they tell you everything from ping time to download time  some of them are LoadRunner, NeoLoad, LoadUI or Webload and neoload i never used any of them but many of clients do use.but it's always good practice to have your own sim cards ready if you are planning to have more apps and more releases every now and then. Mark if it helps ..Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are speaking specifically about the issue of network impairment.  What you are seeing is that the network you are testing on is likely both faster and cleaner than the intended network in production.   Mobile devices have a longer "latch time" on the stack due to the characteristics of the network than the same application on a clean network.   This higher latch time causes a higher percentage of resources to be dedicated to "ring 0" type activities, those that take priority and must be handled immediately, related to network.  This means that the total resource pool that the application layer, "ring 3" activities can draw from is diminished.   The net-net of all of this, you can bring down performance on a server with fewer mobile clients versus desktop.

There are a few paths here.   The industry benchmark for impairment was the solution set from Shunra, particularly the hardware devices.  Shunra was scooped up by HP a couple of years ago so if you want to go that route you are likely in the LoadRunner camp.   With Shunra absent as an independent solution a number of players have added network impairment to their tools.   I think both SOASTA and Neotys are in this camp.

There are some build your own models as well.  You can use two small routers with a single line between them and then assign characteristics to this line related to speed and error rate which match the characteristics of mobile networks.   You will need data for these - OOKLA is the default source for line profiles in the industry.  You have what were the competitors to Shunra on the network simulation front: Ixia Communications, Spirent, Agilent.   Their solution sets are much more geared at the OSI layer 2 crowd.   There is also WANEM, an open source solution, but it lacks the complex modeling capabilities.   Also, do not run it in a Virtual Machine - Network impairment needs a consistent and precise system clock, something that the virtualized clock in a virtual machine cannot provide.